# Shared element transition in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to animate my image logo from Screen A to Screen B. In XML based layouts it was possible using `windowContentTransitions` & `transitionName`. So I wanted to ask is something similar available in **Jetpack Compose**?

I have already seen this https://github.com/mobnetic/compose-shared-element

But, Is there something in-built functionality similar to the XML?

Answer (score 1):

Not supported yet by compose. See this conversation on kotlin-lang: https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1616517641495500?thread_ts=1616516302.494300&cid=CJLTWPH7S

Comment: Is there a discussion that is open to the public? You need an @jetbrains.com email to access that.

Comment: @eva no, anyone can register https://kotlinlang.org/community/

Comment: The slack on that page is not the same as the slack in the link